# YII - unit testing not working

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

When I run PHP unit test with YII framework I got following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Function 'phpunit_autoload' not found (function 'phpunit_autoload' not found or invalid function name)' in /var/www/yii/framework/YiiBase.php:628
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an issue with the YII CTestCase.php(yii/framework/test/CTestCase.php). Got a solution, now it works like a charm.
Here it is:

Use:

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php');
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
```

instead of:

```
require_once('PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php'); // workaround for PHPUnit <= 3.6.11
require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
spl_autoload_unregister('phpunit_autoload');
Yii::registerAutoloader('phpunit_autoload');
```

Answer (score 0):

That bug got fixed in Yii 1.1.13

See this Github issue:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1563

and here's the line in the CHANGELOG:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/CHANGELOG#L119